# Wordpress on OpenLiteSpeed CyberPanel get 404 error after VPS reboot

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, vps, litespeed

i get **404 error** after reboot my vps that host `wordpress` using `openlitespeed`.

All version are latest using Digital Ocean Marketplace (just build today). My VPS run **CyberPanel** (Hosting Control Panel for LiteSpeed), so multiple website can host in my vps.

[image]

my effort so far:

1. reboot litespeed using `sudo service lsws restart`
2. change `.htacess` (on Wordpress `/home/example.com/public_html`) like below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

but above steps cant solve the **404 error**

Now, even access file `test.txt` (like `example.com/test.txt`) give error **403 / forbidden** (even using chmod 777).

any idea ?

Thank You In Advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just want to update the result here in case anyone interested.

The permission of the /home/example.com/public_html folder was incorrect, that's why the web server has no permission to read the file. After fixing the folder permission, there's no 404 issue more, even after server rebooting.

Comment: What was the correct permission?

Comment: Did you figure out the correct permissions?

Answer (score 0):

i fix this problem by running this commend:

```
sudo systemctl restart lsws
```

Answer (score -1):

I want to add another note check in cyberpanel if the package is out of space it gave me a 4040 the package default for example and fix the size and save.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).